# How to find the right ZSH $fpath at CMake time (Linux distro differences)?

Tags: installation, cmake, zsh, tab-completion

## Situation

Software author wants to add zsh completion to his project. [Has written completion script](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/pull/5286), works.

Needs to figure out where under `$CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to install so it gets found by default.

## Problem

Testing Fedora 34 against Ubuntu 20.04, it was found that the only common member of `$fpath` is /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions; none of the /usr/share fpaths overlap. Especially, Ubuntu does *not* read /usr/share/zsh/site-functions.

So, I can't just install into `$CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/share/zsh/site-functions`, because that only works for `$CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX==/usr/local`, but not later in packaging (`$CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX==/usr`). I'd argue this is a Ubuntu inconsistency, but that doesn't effectively matter.

## Question

Is there a sensible way to figure out at CMake time where to put completion scripts?

Note that CMake is *not* usually run from zsh, so checking `$fpath` is not an option.

Comment: "Note that CMake is not usually run from zsh, so checking $fpath is not an option." - Inside CMake script you could run (via `execute_process`) `zsh` and pass it some script or code. That script (code) would e.g. print `$fpath`. Then (in CMake script) you could test printed value against some patterns, and make appropriate choice for where to install files in your project.

Comment: hm, true, @Tsyvarev, but that feels *a lot* like I'd rely on a user's ZSH configuration (which might add a lot to fpath that's not in there system-wide), so if I'm completely honest, I'd prefer to not do that. But the idea isn't bad, I could do something like `zsh -dfi -c '...'` or so to get a better feeling for what's there. Still, there's going to be a lot of regular expression application and guessing which of the resulting paths is appropriate, and that's not really "sensible", I guess :/ But it's the best lead I've got so far, thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your considerations about `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` being equal to `/usr` or `/usr/local`. Generally, if a project is configured with `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` equal to `/usr`, then it is intended to work **only if** installed according to that prefix. E.g. if you configure the project with prefix `/usr`, but (manually) place resulted files according to prefix `/usr/local`, the project is not intended to work. A packaging is some sort of installing a project into **other machine**. Only location of files on that other machine which matters.

Comment: @Tsyvarev exactly! So, if I set the prefix to `/usr`, I mustn't install things under `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions`, but under `/usr/share/site-functions`, right? Problem is, that one isn't used on Ubuntu. It's inconsistent: the default fpath on Ubuntu doesn't look at the same directories under /usr/local as under /usr.

Comment: When a project is packaged for a standard project manager, it is passed an installation prefix. That installation prefix is **distro-specific**: E.g. they could use `/usr` for Fedora and `/usr/local` for Ubuntu. This is why `zsh` is configured for use different `$fpath` on different distros. (Aside from the installation prefix, some other directories from [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) could be distro-specific too.) So for build the completion project for Fedora, you need to configure it with use prefix `/usr`, but for Ubuntu you need to use `/usr/local`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev that's incorrect. For Fedora, I don't "need" to use /usr, and for Ubuntu I don't "need" to use /usr/local. Both distros' packaging guidelines explicitly forbid using /usr/local when packaging something! The question is also about something else, namely, how do I figure out which path to *use* given that I have a prefix specified by the user (or using the default prefix).

Comment: Prefixes `/usr` and `/usr/local` was just an example, which seems to be not good. Technically, if your project zsh completion provides some **files for other project** (zsh), then installation of these files is NOT affected by `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` of your project. This installation is affected by **parameters** for that **other project**. E.g. zsh has parameter `--enable-site-fndir=<DIR>`, which is responsible for location of `site-functions/` directory. According to [that answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26558), exactly this directory is intended for functions of 3d-party packages.

Comment: From my understanding, parsing `$fpath` of zsh and finding a directory ended with `/site-functions` would be the most reliable way for choosing directory for your files. You could also provide a parameter (say, `ZSH_SITE_FUNCTIONS_DIR`) which allows the user to redefine automatic selection of the directory.

Comment: that's a pretty good suggestion, thanks!

Comment: You could have multiple copies of zsh installed. Trying to run it and parse out $fpath is just a mess. People will end up needing to disable that when creating packages with fixed paths. `--enable-site-fndir=` is analagous to things like `--mandir=`. `--enable-additional-fpath=` was added to make it easier to add things like `/usr/local/..` which on Linux tends to be left for the local system administrator. That does mostly get used so will work for local sys admin installs of gnuradio to `/usr/local`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/share/zsh/site-functions` is the right place.

It is the same with man pages, info pages, pkg-config path, binaries and libraries and whatever else. On a default install, man will only look in predefined places like `/usr/share/man` and `/usr/local/share/man`.

If someone decides to install to `/opt/gnuradio` or whatever, it is then also their responsibility to ensure that they set `$PATH`, `$MANPATH` `$INFOPATH` and whatever else accordingly. It is the same for `$fpath`. The best software can do is ensure that they stick to established conventions and not to spew files elsewhere on the filesystem outside of `$PREFIX`.

If Ubuntu wants to be clever and invent their own `vendor-completion` directories then a consequence of that is that is that they need to patch everything they package that includes a zsh completion. That's their problem because they created the problem for themselves.